# Unable to open localhost pages in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iis

Whenever I try to launch a page in google chrome, it does not connect due to an improper security certificate. I have enabled the Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost. experimental feature in chrome, but it still gives the same SSL error.
google chrome always gives me the same error message: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: The actual error page by Chrome tells clearly what the cause is (such as `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`), so you cannot skip that in the question body.

Comment: sorry, added the error message.

Comment: What kind of Windows are you running? Protocol errors commonly happen on end-of-life Windows releases (like XP), but not likely Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10, up to date.

Comment: Then you don't have many options. Install openssl on Windows and see what it says when connecting via HTTPS, https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html That might give some hints, but not quite many.

Comment: Could you access the website with IIS self-signed certificate？You could try to generate a valid certificate from makcert tool.https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/.   If it doesn't work, could you fix it by the steps in this link?https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-fix-err-ssl-protocol-error